# Keep user logged in using shared preference and json

Tags: android, json

I Know what is shared preference and json parsing. Using these how to keep user logged in. I just want the app to first check for shared preference folder and if not found go to login activity. I only need the flow of code and logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use :

```
public class AppPrefrances {
protected static AppPrefrances INSTANCE;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;

public static AppPrefrances getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new AppPrefrances();
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}

public void clear() {
    prefs.edit().clear().apply();
}

public void setLogin(boolean isLogin) {
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLogin", isLogin).apply();
}

public boolean getLogin() {
    return prefs.getBoolean("isLogin", false);
}

}
```

Then in your activity :

```
if(!AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext().getLogin){
//go to login

}
```

When you parse json :

```
AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLogin(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. It's simple:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean logged_in = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("logged_in", false);

if (logged_in) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogIn.class);
}
```

Put this code in your first activity that is opened on application startup, and change `MainActivity.this` to your activity name. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a Boolean in the SharedPreferences.

On the first activity that starts you can check the boolean, if it's logged in you go directly to the main activity. If not, go to login page.